# Upload image using Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need to upload a given image using Amazon S3

I have this PHP:

```
<?
$uploaddir = 'images/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Data Uploaded Successfully";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

but it gives me this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Error>
    <Code>MethodNotAllowe</Code>
    <Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
    <ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
    <Method>POST</Method>
    ....
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    ....
</Error>
```

How can I upload a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `POST` method (which is PHP defaults) to submit the data. Most webapplications differenciate between the verbs `GET`, `PUT` and `POST` (see [W3 RFC on Verbs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)).

S3 wants you to use `<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>` as the method. move_uploaded_file isn't able to do that. Before you start writing code for doing PUT requests, maybe you should take a look at some [PHP S3 libs](http://www.neurofuzzy.net/2006/03/17/amazon-s3-php-class/).

Answer (score 5):

Have a try at Zend Framework, there is a great class (Zend_Service_Amazon_S3) to handle all your S3 hassle.

http://framework.zend.com

```
require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php';
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($my_aws_key, $my_aws_secret_key);
$s3->createBucket("my-own-bucket");
$s3->putObject("my-own-bucket/myobject", $file);
```