# Upload Multiple object to amazon s3

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiple instagram url and i am converting it to Nsdata.I have also number of images of iphone, and i am also converting iphone images to Nsdata. How should i pass this Nsdata to Amazone s3 in ios ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385537/upload-image-using-amazon-s3?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS SDK for iOS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) which includes a sample which covers [uploading photos to S3](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271).